# error: display Surface quit

Tags: pygame

when i run my program it dosn't fill the screen with white, which it should i think(IM NEW). Iv check other games iv written and i seem to be doing the same stuff but it works in the other ones? here's my program:

```
import pygame,time,pygame.mixer
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
#set screen to be the window 
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((640,480))
#fills screen with white
screen.fill((255,255,255))
#set starting gravity
gravity=0.1
#limits fps
FPS=60
fpstime=pygame.time.Clock()
timer=0
#sets colour codes
red=(255,0,0)
green=(0,255,0)
blue=(0,255,0)
white=(255,255,255)
#set player starting location
playerpos1=320
playerpos2=240
#makes the game loop start
FLYING=True
#game loop

while FLYING:
    screen.fill((255,255,255))
    gravity+=0.02
    timer+=0.001
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            break



    pygame.display.update
    fpstime.tick(FPS)
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible issue - you're missing `()` on `pygame.display.update()`.

Comment: You're welcome! Please select my answer as correct if it indeed fixes your issue.